# How do I find the width of a uint_fast32_t

Tags: c, printf, stdint

I'd like to be able to portably `fprintf()` a `uint_fast32_t` as defined in `stdint.h` with all leading zeroes. For instance if my platform defined `uint_fast32_t` as a 64-bit unsigned integer, I would want to `fprintf()` with a format specifier like `%016lX`, but if it's a 32-bit unsigned integer, I would want to use `%08lX`.

Is there a macro like `INTFAST32_BITS` somewhere that I could use?

right now I'm using

```
#if UINT_FAST32_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFF
#    define FORMAT "08"PRIXFAST32
#elif UINT_FAST32_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
#    define FORMAT "016"PRIXFAST32
#endif
```

But this only works with `uint_fast32_t` that is exactly 32 or 64 bits wide, and the code is also kinda clunky and hard to read

Comment: You are guaranteed that your `uint_fast32_t` will have `"have at least the specified width"` [C11 Standard - 7.20.1.3 Fastest minimum-width integer types](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.3). So you are guaranteed 32-bits. Why doesn't that satisfy your constraint. It will either be 32-bit or 64-bit but not smaller.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin They probably want to generalize to an hypothetical `uint48_t` or `uint128_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the size of a `uint_fast32_t` the same way you can find the size of any other type: by applying the `sizeof` operator to it.  The unit of the result is the size of type `char`.  Example:

```
size_t chars_in_a_uint_fast32_t = sizeof(uint_fast32_t);
```

But this is not sufficient for printing one with one of the `printf`-family functions.  Undefined behavior arises in `printf` *et. al.* if any formatting directive is mismatched with the type of the corresponding argument, and the size of of `uint_fast32_t` is not sufficient information to make a proper match.

This is where the formatting macros already described in [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62092856/2402272) come in.  These provide the appropriate size modifier and conversion letter for each type and conversion.  For an `X` conversion of `uint_fast32_t`, the appropriate macro is `PRIXFAST32`.

You provide any flags, field width, and precision as normal.  If indeed you want to use a field width that is adapted to the actual size of `uint_fast32_t`, then a reasonable way to do that would be to avail yourself of the option to specify that the field width is passed as an argument (of type `int`).  Thus:

```
uint_fast32_t fast;
// ...
printf("%0*" PRIXFAST32 "\n", (int) sizeof(fast) * 2, fast);
```

I note, however, that this seems a little questionable, inasmuch as you are making provision for values wider than generally you should allow any value of that type to become.  The `printf` function will not in any case print fewer digits than are required to express the value, supposing that it is indeed of the specified type, so I would be inclined to simply use a fixed field width sufficient for 32-bit integers (say 8).

Comment: Re “… provision for values wider than you should allow any value of that type to become”: Not necessarily. It is reasonable to, for example, write code for multiprecision arithmetic that requires at least 32-bit units but adapts to anything larger the implementation offers.